# Is it possible to solve a system of PDEs using sympy in Python?

Tags: python, sympy, equation, pde

Assume that you have a system of coupled PDEs, such as

> 1st PDE in F(a,b)
>
> 2nd PDE in F(a,b)

Following code is able to solve each one of the PDEs separately:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp

# definition of variables
a, b = sp.symbols('a b')
f = sp.Function('f')
F = f(a, b)
Fda = F.diff(a)
Fdb = F.diff(b)

# definition of PDEs
eq1 = Fda - 2
eq2 = Fda + Fdb + 2

# solution of separated PDEs
sp.pprint(sp.pdsolve(eq1))
sp.pprint(sp.pdsolve(eq2))
```

Is it possible to solve the system of PDEs? The syntax would be something like `sp.pprint(sp.pdsolve([eq1, eq2]))`. I have tried `[eq1, eq2]`, `{eq1, eq2}`, `np.array([eq1, eq2])` etc. I had a look at `help(sp.pdsolve)` and `help(sp.pde)`, but have not yet found a solution.

Answer (score 3):

No, the solution of systems of partial differential equations is not implemented. What actually is implemented:

1. Solving a 1st order linear PDE with constant coefficients: the general form of solution is known and is hardcoded in the solver; the solver returns it, with given coefficients plugged in.
2. Solving a 1st order linear PDE with variable coefficients, by converting it to  an ODE (known as the method of characteristics). A single PDE only.

*Aside*: I'm skeptical of symbolic solution of PDE in general, and of systems especially. It's just not a thing that happens outside of carefully composed textbook examples. Either a textbook recipe applies (for textbook problems), or there is a hidden structure to be uncovered with human ingenuity (rare), or there is no symbolic solution to be found.

Answer (score 2):

Since your system is separable, it can be solved with `dsolve`. However, `dsolve` currently doesn't like things like `f(a, b)`, so you need to manually solve the slices. You also need to manually replace the constants with functions:

```
>>> fa, fb = symbols('fa fb', cls=Function)
>>> eq1 = fb(a).diff(a) - 2
>>> eq2 = fb(a).diff(a) - fa(b).diff(b) + 2
>>> dsolve(eq1, fb(a))
Eq(fb(a), C1 + 2*a)
>>> fbsol = dsolve(eq1, fb(a)).subs(Symbol("C1"), Function("Ca")(b))
>>> fbsol
Eq(fb(a), 2*a + Ca(b))
>>> eq2.subs(*fbsol.args).doit()
Derivative(fa(b), b) + 4
>>> fasol = dsolve(eq2.subs(*fbsol.args).doit(), fa(b)).subs(Symbol("C1"), Function("Cb")(a))
>>> fasol
Eq(fa(b), -4*b + Cb(a))
>>> fbsol
Eq(fb(a), 2*a + Ca(b))
```

From here it should be clear that `Cb(a) = 2*a + C` and `Ca(b) = -4*b + C`, giving the solution `f(a, b) = 2*a - 4*b + C`, which you can check satisfies the original.

This is definitely something that `pdsolve` should be able to do automatically, but not much is implemented there yet.